# How to define an xpath expression that only retrieves hyphenated elements from the first of two similar divs?

Tags: xpath

The divs below appear in that order in the HTML I am parsing.

```
//div[contains(@class,'top-container')]//font/text()
```

I'm using the xpath expression above to try to get any data in the first div below in which a hyphen is used to delimit the data:

```
Wednesday - Chess at Higgins Stadium
Thursday - Cook-off
```

The problem is I am getting data from the second div below such as:

```
Monday 10:00 - 11:00
Tuesday 10:00 - 11:00
```

How do I only retrieve the data from the first div? (I also want to exclude any elements in the first div that do not contain this hyphenated data)?

```
<div class="top-container"> 
<div dir="ltr"> 
<div dir="ltr"><font face="Arial" color="#000000" size="2">Wednesday - Chess at Higgins Stadium</font></div> 
<div dir="ltr"><font face="Arial" size="2">Thursday - Cook-off</font></div> 
<div dir="ltr"><font face="Arial" size="2"></font>&nbsp;</div> 
<div dir="ltr">&nbsp;</div> 
<div dir="ltr"><font face="Arial" color="#000000" size="2"></font>&nbsp;</div>
</div> 

<div dir="ltr"> 
<div RE><font face="Arial"> 
<div dir="ltr"> 
<div RE><font face="Arial" size="2"><strong>Alex Dawkin </strong></font></div> 
<div RE><font face="Arial" size="2">Monday 10:00 - 11:00 </font></div> 
<div RE><font size="2">Tuesday 10:00 - 11:00 </font></div> 
<div RE> 
<div RE><font face="Arial" size="2"></font></div><font face="Arial" size="2"></font></div> 
<div RE>&nbsp;</div> 
<div RE>&nbsp;</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XPATH was matching on ***any*** `font` element that is a descendant of `<div class="top-container">`.

`div[1]` will address the first `div` child element of the "top-container" element. If you add that to your XPATH, it will return the desired results.

```
//div[contains(concat(' ',@class,' '),' top-container '))]/div[1]//font/text()
```

**If you want to ensure that only `text()` nodes that contain "-" are addressed, then you should also add a predicate filter to the `text()`.**

```
//div[contains(concat(' ',@class,' '),' top-container '))]/div[1]//font/text()[contains(.,'-')]
```

---

> Instead of checking only for nodes
>   that contain "-", how would you modify
>   the last expression to just check for
>   non-empty strings?

If you want to return any `text()` node with a value, then the predicate filter on `text()` is not necessary. If a text node doesn't have content, then it isn't a text node and won't be selected.

However, **if you only want to select `text()` nodes that contain text other than whitespace**, you could use this expression:

```
//div[contains(concat(' ',@class,' '),' top-container '))]/div[1]//font/text()[normalize-space()]
```

`normalize-space()` removes any leading and trailing whitespace characters.  So, if the `text()` only contained whitespace(including `&nbsp;`), the result would be nothing and evaluate to `false()` in the predicate filter, so only `text()` containing something other than whitespace will be selected.

Comment: Boolean value of a string is true only if it's not an empty string. So, `text()[normalize-string()]` is enough for select not white space only text nodes. Also, if `font` elements contains only a text node, then `font[contains(.,'-')]` is enough for select `font` elements having `-` character in their string value. At last if you really want to test a `@class` use `contains(concat(' ',@class,' '),' class-to-test ')`.

Comment: Good points @Alejandro.  I've updated the answer to use the simplified predicate filter for non-whitespace `text()`, and more safe match for `@class` value